# How to use typescript modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

It can seem banal for you but hopelessly I couldn't use one Typescript module ([device-detector-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-detector-js)) in my Node.js project.

Now, Please know that I searched the web "How to use typescript modules in Node.js", all I find is "Building a Node.js App with TypeScript"; I think this is different, isn't it ?

Now, back to my case, installing **device-detector-js** then putting `import DeviceDetector = require("device-detector-js");` yields this error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a "TypeScript module", it's an npm package.

If your code is using CommonJS module format, then you can import a package with the syntax `const DeviceDetector = require("device-detector-js")`.

If it's using EcmaScript module format (ESM), so not in your case, you can import with `import * as DeviceDetector from "device-detector-js"`.

The syntax you are trying isn't valid in either case.

See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) about how to tell Node that your code is using EcmaScript module format, if you wish to do that.

Comment: While the syntax is indeed wrong, doesn't the error arise already from the `import` usage itself?

Comment: @aviya.developer, yes, it does, that `import` should just be `const` (or `var` for very old Node versions)